# What is the best way to handle existing data in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am in the process of learning Backbone.js. I love what I am seeing but something is not clear for me... What is the best way to handle the data that is already on the page. Is is better to go trough all of them and create a model for each.

```
$('element').each(function() {
     var model = new Model();
     collection.add(model);
});
```

Or should I load the page, then fetch the data and handle it from there.

Or again, is there a better way to do this, something that I missed?

**Edit**

If server side I loop trough my data to bootstrap it with the page

*server side*

```
<div>
    <p>{{ model.someInformation }}</p>
</div>
```

Should I instantiate a new model directly?

```
<script>
    Backbone.Model.extend({
        var model = new Model();
    });
</script>
```

I read about Collection reset at bootstrap http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap but there seem to be something I'm not getting... I thought I needed models to add to a collection, if I don't have my models instantiated somewhere what is the use to `reset` the collection... I am a bit lost here.

**Edit 2**

I've been able to make my app working doing the following:

```
$('#active-cards .card').each(function(i) {
     window['card' + i] = new Card(),
         window['cardView' + i] = new CardView({ el: $(this) });
         id = $(this).attr('id'),
         name = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val(),
         client =  $(this).find('input[name="client"]').val(),
         field =  $(this).find('input[name="field"]').val();
     window['card' + i].set({ id: id, name: name, client: client, field: field });
     cards.add(window['card' + i]);
});
```

After this I can find the model by doing

```
var id = this.$el.attr('id');
var card = cards.get(id);
```

Comment: what do you mean by "data is already on the page"?

Comment: I mean probably mean bootstraping the data server side. *Check my edit maybe it will helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you generally would not do it like that. It looks like you're looking to populate a collection on page load. The backbone documentation has a [section on this](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap), it's referred to as bootstrapping.

**Edit to answer comment**
It may be a strange concept to get your head around, but you do not need to instantiate a model before adding to a collection. As per the reset documentation:

> Use reset to replace a collection with a new list of models (or
>   attribute hashes)

So, with Collections you can specify the [`model` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model), and then simply add an array of object literals. For example:

```
UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: User
});
myUserCollection = new UserCollection();
myUserCollection.reset([
   {
      name: "Bob",
      age: 25
   }, {
      name: "Foo",
      age: 26
   }
]);
```

`myUserCollection` will now contain 2 `User` models.

**Second Edit**
I still don't think you're quite getting the concept. Here's what I think you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/67E6t/

Comment: You answer is helping but I'm still not yet sure how to handle it. Please check my edit, I am trying to explain my problem more.

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your question edits. Hopefully clears things up for you.

Comment: Ok I understand your explanation. But I feel like I still have to do a `.each()` to instantiate the models in the `.reset()` call. Right now I get is all to work by doing as per my other edit.

Comment: I still don't think you're quite getting the concept. Please see my second edit, where i've created a working jsfiddle of what I believe you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok following your example, you suggest a create a card variable serverside containing all the bootstrapped data and then a instantiate my view from this?

Comment: instantiate your **collection** from this, yes.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so very much for your time and answers. Though I have one last question: somehow, what's the difference between you solution and mine? Meaning, since mine works, why yours is better? - I'm asking so I can understand the backbone philosophy better :P

Comment: Would seem this is the last response I can stick here. With your approach you are almost defeating the object of Backbone. It's philosophy is to bring MVC to JS. By simply iterating over existing HTML to create `Model`'s and `View'` is backwards. Don't forget to mark it as a solution if you think it will help future users suffering with the same issue.

Comment: I believe the problem is only coming from my first understanding of Backbone, I thought it would only help me structure my code better but it is actually way to powerful for my needs since all the backend and data handling is already took care of serverside. Thank you for bringing light on my problems.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to bootstrap your initial models to a collection, you would like to directly put your initial models to the collection from server side.

```
<script>
  var myCol = new Backbone.Collection;
  accounts.reset(models_prepared_in_server>); //you utilize your server side to replace the models_prepared_in_server with your actual data.
</script>
```

so, when the page is transferred to client side, your code could looks like (as an example):

```
<script>
  var myCol = new Backbone.Collection;
  myCol.reset([
     { name: model1,
       some_prop: prop_value;
     },
     { name: model2,
       some_prop: prop_value2;
     }
  ]);
</script>
```

So, after the script is executed by your browser, the `myCol` is filled with your models.

Comment: That probably mean that Backbone need to be loaded in the head right?
And do you see a major difference between doing that and instantiating the models with a `.each()` function?